# jquery onclick function not doing what it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have the following jquery, which on clicking #block4, .maincontent shows. This works fine at first, to show and then hide the div. Once you clcik it again after the initial first 2 times, the .maincontent div shows and then disappears straight away.

```
$('#block4').click(function(){
   $(".maincontent").delay(500).fadeIn();
   $("#block4").click(hideIt)
});

function hideIt() {
   $(".maincontent").fadeOut();
};
```

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: You never detach `hideIt`... moreover, you add it as _another_ handler everytime you click `block4`. So, `hideIt` is fired multiple times.

Comment: two same element id nested click events.... oooopssy

Comment: I'd suggest [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) in this context. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't do this. Better set a class or any flag you might need :

```
$('#block4').click(function(){
 var $cont=$(".maincontent");
    if(!$cont.hasClass('visible'))
        $cont.addClass('visible').delay(500).fadeIn();
    else
        $cont.removeClass('visible').fadeOut();
});
```

As for your solution try disabling the previous event :

```
$("#block4").off('click').click(hideIt);
```

or better use `.one` although I prefer the `class` solution :

```
$('#block4').one('click',function(){
   $(".maincontent").delay(500).fadeIn();
   $("#block4").one('click',hideIt);
});
```

Comment: It'd be a lot simpler to just use the :visibility selector than manage more classes for things jQuery does out of the box.

Comment: @MikeThomsen maybe... I prefer controlling the classes and usually I need to style the components. If it's just showing or hiding then yeah I agree. And I forgot this jquery selector ;)

Comment: btw for `:visible` you should note that `Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout`

Answer (score 3):

Why not just do it like this?

```
$('#block4').click(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
       $(".maincontent").fadeOut();
   }
   else {
       $(".maincontent").delay(500).fadeIn();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use toggle)

```
$('#block4').click(function() {
  $(".maincontent").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You attach `hideIt` everytime you click `block4`. So, `hideIt` is fired **multiple times** when you try to show `maincontent`.

Based on the code you've provided, I'd suggest that you check out `jQuery.fadeToggle()`

```
$('#block4').click(function(){
    $(".maincontent").fadeToggle(500);
});
```

This will alternate between fading in/out each click.

Here's a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/WQgnE/).